# Save active record object without reference id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following migrations:

```
 class CreateMothers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
       def change
         create_table :mothers do |t|
           t.string :name

           t.timestamps
         end
       end
     end
```

and:

```
class CreateSons < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
   def change
     create_table :sons do |t|
       t.string :name
       t.references :mother

       t.timestamps
     end
   end
 end
```

Whenever I try to save a Son object with the mother_id field blank, I get the error: "Mother must exist"

Is there a way to save this without the mother_id field?

Comment: Do you have validation for which checks the presence of `mother_id` in your `Son` model? If so you need to remove that validation to save the Son object with `mother_id` field blank.

Comment: There's no validation. But it works perfectly fine when I remove belongs_to :mother from the Son model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Son` model, just add the `optional` param to make it work:

```
class Son < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :mother, optional: true
end
```

In default, rails set it to be `true`, so let use `false` instead, the detail was described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#optional)

Comment: Thanks a lot! you're a genius.